# Diagnostic checks before and after adjusting for standard errors in R

Tags: regression, clustering, standard-error, sandwich

Currently, I'm fitting a regression model for my dataset. As there are clusters, I refitted the model using the `coeftest()` function from the `sandwich` package. And finally, I want to check the usual model assumptions. Which model will I use to check the assumptions (model with adjusted or unadjusted standard error)? As far as I understand, the model coefficients are exactly the same. I'm asking this question because I'm unable to produce diagnostic plots based on the model with adjusted standard error. I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CV. I fixed an apparent typo in your question, please check that that is what you want.  Can you show the code you tried? Did you look at the vignettes in the sandwich package?